# Can I use GParted to repartition my drive in order that I can install Windows 7 on a portion of the drive and have a dual-boot system?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have used Ubuntu 11.10 successfully for several months.  Today, I am installing the 12.04 LTS upgrade.  It's been a while since I set up an old Lenovo Thinkpad T60 with Ubuntu.  Windows XP was formerly only the machine, but it crashed beyond repair.  Therefore, as I recollect, I formatted the disk to serve only as an Ubuntu machine.

Recently, I have had the opportunity to test drive Windows 7 Professional, and I like it.  My question is "Can I use GParted to repartition my drive in order that I can install Windows 7 on a portion of the drive and have a dual-boot system?"  If GParted is not the preferred utility for accomplishing this task, what partition management software would you recommend?

Thanks very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Gparted is fine, just remember not to shrink your partition to much or you will lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

GParted is a fine tool, but as always, remember to keep a backup of important data. One other thing: you can't change (shrink/expand/format) a partition already in use. So it is best if you do it from an Ubuntu Live CD. It already has GParted on it.

And if you are up for separating your Home folder and other files, which is generally considered good practice, you might want to read the [Ubuntu Partitioning Scheme](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes) from the Ubuntu docs.

Hope it helps.